# Pandas read_csv usecols same index

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO
x='''
a,b,c,d
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
9,10,11,12
13,14,15,16
17,18,19,20
'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(x), skipinitialspace=True, usecols=[2,3,2])
print df
```

Output:

```
    c   d
0   3   4
1   7   8
2  11  12
3  15  16
4  19  20
```

is there any way i can get

```
    c   d    c
0   3   4    3
1   7   8    7
2  11  12    11
3  15  16    15
4  19  20    19
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [iloc[]](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) indexer:

```
In [67]: pd.read_csv(StringIO(x), skipinitialspace=True).iloc[:, [2,3,2]]
Out[67]:
    c   d   c
0   3   4   3
1   7   8   7
2  11  12  11
3  15  16  15
4  19  20  19
```

But as [@Boud has already mentioned in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41450157/pandas-read-csv-usecols-same-index/41450205#comment70107331_41450205) it would be much more efficient to make use of `usecols` parameter (as we don't need to parse columns that we don't need and we won't waste memory for them), if you know either names of columns in the CSV file:

```
In [6]: pd.read_csv(StringIO(x), skipinitialspace=True, usecols=[2,3,2]).loc[:, ['c','d','c']]
Out[6]:
    c   d   c
0   3   4   3
1   7   8   7
2  11  12  11
3  15  16  15
4  19  20  19
```

or if you know their **new** indexes (in the new DataFrame):

```
In [7]: pd.read_csv(StringIO(x), skipinitialspace=True, usecols=[2,3,2]).iloc[:, [0,1,0]]
Out[7]:
    c   d   c
0   3   4   3
1   7   8   7
2  11  12  11
3  15  16  15
4  19  20  19
```

PS you may also want to read about [Pandas boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Comment: Brilliant!!!!!!can you just describe your answer and put if there are any difference in my approach and urs?I have to use to read over 45 million lines from 200 files

Comment: `iloc[:, [2,3,2]]` is a positional indexer.  `:` says to take all rows.  `[2,3,2]` says to take columns in positions 2, 3, and 2.  You could have also done `loc[:, ['c', 'd', 'c']]`

Comment: @piRSquared thanx a lot........why doesnt `usecols` work d same way? r der any constraints on using `iloc`

Comment: @vks theres no magic behind it.  It was a design choice.  If I had to guess, it conflicts with many of the integrity checks that go on behind the scenes.  Truth is, I'm not sure.

Comment: usecols argument is parsed in parsers.py in function `def _validate_usecols_arg(usecols)`. This function returns set(usecols) so the dupe column is removed by design. If you think about it, that makes sense, as a good practice should be to parse once the columns of interest, and then `reindex_axis(['c', 'd', 'c', axis=1)` for I/O and parsing optimization.

Comment: PS: which means @MaxU I would keep usecols argument to still refrain from parsing useless columns

Comment: @Boud when we r using `iloc` why do we need `usecols`

Comment: @vks to avoid parsing useless columns in read_csv. The current answer above will parse columns a, b, c, d for your 45M rows, then throw away a and b. CPU and memory waste IMHO

Comment: @Boud so u mean we should use both?

Comment: Correct. Basically you first load the necessary data (read_csv with usecols), and then you present the data the way you want (iloc with redundant columns)

Comment: @Boud, thank you! I was away for some time... I've corrected the answer now